# float property does not work

Tags: css-float

I have a problem with float. The text does not flow the picture from the right side except for the first line. When I create a new html document and insert a picture with description everything works fine. I don't know where the problem is.

Here's the html:

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="logo">
        <h1>Best movies of all time!</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        Shawshank Redemption <br />
        Forrest Gump <br />
        Seven <br />
        The Lord of the Rings <br />
        American Gangster  <br />
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <h2>Shawshank Redemption</h2>

        <p id="shawshank_description">
        <img id="shwashank" src="img/shawshank.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
        The Shawshank Redemption is a 1994 American drama film written and directed by Frank Darabont, and starring Tim Robbins and Morgan Freeman. Adapted from the Stephen King novella   Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption, the film tells the story of Andy Dufresne, a banker who is sentenced to life in Shawshank State Penitentiary for the murder of his wife and her lover, despite his claims of innocence.  During his time at the prison, he befriends a fellow inmate, Ellis Boyd "Red" Redding, and finds himself protected by the guards after the warden begins using  him in his money-laundering operation. Although it was a box office disappointment, the film received multiple award nominations (including seven Oscar nominations) and outstanding reviews from critics for its acting, story, and realism. It has since been successful on cable television, VHS, DVD, and Blu-ray. It was included in the American Film Institute's 100 Years...100 Movies 10th Anniversary Edition.[4] It is considered to be one of the greatest films of all time. The Shawshank Redemption is a 1994 American drama film written and directed by Frank Darabont, and starring Tim Robbins and Morgan Freeman. Adapted from the Stephen King novella    Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption, the film tells the story of Andy Dufresne, a banker who is sentenced to life in Shawshank State Penitentiary for the murder of his wife and her lover, despite his claims of innocence.  
        </p>

    </div>

    <div id="ad">
        <img src="img/banner.gif" />
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Best movies of all time! &copy; All rights reserved
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's the css:

```css
#shawshank {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: You should use chrome dev tools to give you a better idea of what CSS styles are being applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your `float: left` styling is not being applied... Try this:

HTML:

```
<p id="shawshank_description">
  <div class="shank_image">
    <img src="img/shawshank.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
  </div>
  It is considered to be one of the greatest films of all time... 
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.shank_image img{
  float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbbbm514/

Comment: Your solution works. Thank you very much. But you know what, I once again tried to use my code and it works.... I do not really understand why `float: left`  styling was not applied for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file, you need `#shawshank {...}` instead of just `shawshank{...}`, since you are targeting an element by its id. Also I noticed in your code the id property on your image is "shwashank" instead of "shawshank", so that could be an issue too.

Also, your floats may not work with your current nesting of the image inside the paragraph tag, since they are supposed to float alongside each other. Try:

```
<img id="shawshank" src="img/shawshank.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
<p id="shawshank_description">...</p>
```

And in your CSS file add:

```
#shawshank_description {
    float: right;
}
```